# Flutter app's system locale is always en_US on Windows 10

Tags: flutter

What may be a reason that I get `en_US` as system locale from `PlatformDispatcher.instance.locale` and `window.locale` on Windows 10? This is true for debug and release builds. I expect to get `uk_Ua`.

`cmd` output:

```
System Locale:   uk;Ukrainian
Input Locale:    en-us;English (United States)
```

Comment: Did you test this on different devices or computers?

Comment: The same after update to Flutter 3.7.0. I used to get uk_UA correctly, but now I always have en_US. Have you fixed that in some way?

Answer (score 1):

So, that is very strange, but if you go to the Windows language settings, then move Ukrainian language to the top (so it will be default input language), then you will get correct system locale:

[image: Windows language settings]

But if you set the English first, then the app will get en_US.

That is weird, because Ukrainian is selected as country and as the UI language on the same page. It seems like a bug.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/547